# Resolve artifact with sbt programmatically

Tags: sbt

The following blog propose how to fetch an artifact directly from java using ivy (http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2010/11/08/Embed-Ivy-How-to-use-Ivy-with-Java).

```
public class IvyArtifactResolver {
    public File resolveArtifact(String groupId, String artifactId, String version) throws Exception {
        //creates clear ivy settings
        IvySettings ivySettings = new IvySettings();
        //url resolver for configuration of maven repo
        URLResolver resolver = new URLResolver();
        resolver.setM2compatible(true);
        resolver.setName("central");
        //you can specify the url resolution pattern strategy
        resolver.addArtifactPattern(
                "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
                + "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]");
        //adding maven repo resolver
        ivySettings.addResolver(resolver);
        //set to the default resolver
        ivySettings.setDefaultResolver(resolver.getName());
        //creates an Ivy instance with settings
        Ivy ivy = Ivy.newInstance(ivySettings);

        File ivyfile = File.createTempFile("ivy", ".xml");
        ivyfile.deleteOnExit();

        String[] dep = null;
        dep = new String[]{groupId, artifactId, version};

        DefaultModuleDescriptor md =
                DefaultModuleDescriptor.newDefaultInstance(ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(dep[0],
                dep[1] + "-caller", "working"));

        DefaultDependencyDescriptor dd = new DefaultDependencyDescriptor(md,
                ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(dep[0], dep[1], dep[2]), false, false, true);
        md.addDependency(dd);

        //creates an ivy configuration file
        XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(md, ivyfile);

        String[] confs = new String[]{"default"};
        ResolveOptions resolveOptions = new ResolveOptions().setConfs(confs);

        //init resolve report
        ResolveReport report = ivy.resolve(ivyfile.toURL(), resolveOptions);

        //so you can get the jar library
        File jarArtifactFile = report.getAllArtifactsReports()[0].getLocalFile();

        return jarArtifactFile;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if sbt exposes this kind of interface since it uses ivy.

resolve :: ModuleId -> File

Answer (score 3):

### Scripts, REPL, and Dependencies

There's a document called [Scripts, REPL, and Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Scripts.html) you might be interested in. Script runner for example lets you write something like this:

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-twitter" % "0.8.3",
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.3"
)
*/

import dispatch.{ json, Http, Request }
import dispatch.twitter.Search
```

### driving sbt programmatically

You can also use any subparts of sbt as a library and drive it yourself. Because of the plugin ecosystem, it's pretty good about maintaining binary compatibility among the point releases. The key task that grabs jars would be `update`, so `def updateTask` ([Defaults.scala#L1113](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/5275dcab4b9512f941daceda9fa3d843899612d1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1113)) could be a good place to start. If you are driving sbt from the client code, however, wouldn't you end up re-implementing sbt shell or including all the sbt's dependencies? You might as well have a separate sbt shell window or sbt script section.

### Custom Resolvers

sbt ships with variety of customizable resolvers, so the first place to check out should be: [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html):

> sbt provides an interface to the repository types available in Ivy: file, URL, SSH, and SFTP. A key feature of repositories in Ivy is using patterns to configure repositories.
>
> Construct a repository definition using the factory in `sbt.Resolver` for the desired type. This factory creates a `Repository` object that can be further configured. The following table contains links to the Ivy documentation for the repository type and the API documentation for the factory and repository class. The SSH and SFTP repositories are configured identically except for the name of the factory. Use `Resolver.ssh` for SSH and `Resolver.sftp` for SFTP.

For example you can do:

```scala
resolvers += Resolver.file("my-test-repo", file("test")) transactional()
```

### RawRepository

But if you truly want a programmable resolver, there is `RawRepository`:

```scala
final class RawRepository(val resolver: DependencyResolver) extends Resolver
{
    def name = resolver.getName
    override def toString = "Raw(" + resolver.toString + ")"
}
```

This is a thin wrapper around [`org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DependencyResolver`](https://github.com/apache/ivy/blob/2.3.0-rc1/src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/DependencyResolver.java), which you should be able to write by extending one of the resolvers they have. (I haven't tried this myself.)

Comment: I want to resolve the artifact in the client code during runtime. It's for codebrew.io to specify custom dependency.